# Where does St. Bernard say "A long period of chastity is a second virginity.”?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, sexuality, saint, virginity

Fr. Ludovic-Marie Barrielle, [*Do I Have a Vocation?*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8685), ch. 5, claims:

> “A long period of chastity” says Saint Bernard, “is a second virginity.”

Where does St. Bernard say this?

Comment: I searched Google for this exact phrase. The only results were this question and a page where it appears as a part of a novena meditation: https://devotiontoourlady.com/nv-corpus-christi.html. Does Father Barrielle not have a footnote?

Comment: @jaredad7 Maybe in the French original (which I can't find).